# (Autohotkey) I want to automate my scriptting process

Tags: autohotkey

[image]i need some help.

I want to have an autohotkey script to be compiled, and when i run it I can open SCITE4AutohotkeyScript and change every "A3" in the SCITe4Autohotkeyscript into "A4", and also "INPUT2" to "INPUT3". So basically i just want to automate my scripting process . ( i attached image for clearer understanding ).

But i can't figure it out how to write it in line of code /autohotkey script.

Can somebody help me with this? Thankyou very much.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Sounds like to me you'd be fine with just a simple [StrReplace](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm).

Comment: thankyou very much for your help my friend